# MySQL cross-column comparison to limit number of instances of a value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, comparison

I have a table with ten fields that can all have values within a defined set. I want to select records from this table only where the ten columns do not repeat the same value more than x number of times.

Example:

```
id  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
--------------------------------------------------------
 1  a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i
 2  a     a     a     b     c     d     e     f     g
 3  a     a     a     a     b     c     d     e     f
 4  b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j
 5  c     c     c     c     d     c     c     f     g
```

Given the example table above, I want my SELECT to return records 1, 2 and 4. Rows 3 and 5 each have four or more columns with the same value.

The only idea I've come up with thus far is to concatenate all ten columns and then have iterative instr calls, but this would be very static and not performance-friendly.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: will you only have col1 .. col9? is that fixed?

Comment: If you have a table where a value means the same thing in multiple columns, you have an antipattern in your design.  These values should be stored on individual *rows* in a separate table, linked back to the primary key of the first table... then `JOIN` ... `GROUP BY` ... `HAVING COUNT` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values into one column using `union all` and do the aggregation for each `id`.

```
select id from    
(select id, col1 as col from tablename
union all 
select id, col2 from tablename
union all
...
select id, col9 from tablename) t
group by id
having count(distinct col) > 7 --set this according to your need (10-x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation, after unpivoting the data:

```
select id
from (select id, col, count(*) as cnt
      from ((select id, col1 as col from t) union all
            (select id, col2 as col from t) union all
            . . .
           ) t
      group by id, col
     ) t
where cnt < 4
group by id;
```

There is also a cumbersome and arcane way to do this with no subqueries:

```
select t.* 
from t
where length(replace(concat(col1, . . ., col9), col1, '') < 6 or
      length(replace(concat(col1, . . ., col9), col2, '') < 6 or
      . . .;
```

This concatenates the values in the columns together and then removes each value.  The above only works when the values are one character.  A slight variation works for any length:

```
select t.* 
from t
where replace(concat(concat_ws(',', col1, . . ., col9), ','),
              concat(col1, ',')) not like '%,%,%,%,%,%,%' or
      . . .
```